hosting a Redhat 8 network install on LAN
If I have an operational server running RHEL-8.10 on a LAN as 192.168.1.1, is it possible to host a network installation of rhel-8.10-x86_64-dvd.iso downloaded from Redhat which is ~14gb, such that when I boot another [new] server which would be on 192.168.1.2 I can somehow F11 boot manager and install Linux?
if so, what is involved?  I am tired of using a usb stick to boot from; if I can forego using some external media and make use of an operational server on the LAN I would prefer to.

What you are thinking of is known as a PXE network installation service and possibly a Kickstart installation.
It needs the following component services:

a BOOTP/DHCP server that allows custom DHCP options to be specified (so something more configurable than a typical home router's built-in DHCP server is needed)
a TFTP server service for providing the initial boot files (although newer systems' netboot firmware may support HTTP too)
some better-performance file sharing service for providing the rest of the installation files, either as a ISO image or as a mounted directory hierarchy (today a HTTP server is a common choice, but a NFS server is a possible option too)

All these components can be on the same server, although they don't have to be.
It's nice to have a NTP server available too, so that the installer can automatically set the system clocks of the new systems to the correct time; but strictly speaking it is not absolutely necessary.
The first step is configuring a DHCP server to supply its clients a boot server IP address and a boot filename. Since DHCP is essentially an extension of BOOTP, you can provide these in two ways: either as BOOTP boot server (siaddr) and boot filename parameters, or as DHCP options #66 and #67. Some netboot firmwares may have bugs in handling one or the other form, so you may have to test both ways to find which one works best for your hardware.
Optimally, you might configure the DHCP server to detect the vendor-class-identifier option of the DHCP request, and only supply the netboot options if the first 9 characters of that option contain the string PXEClient. But if your network does not contain any other systems that might use those netboot DHCP options, you could configure the DHCP server to supply the netboot parameters to all clients; the clients that are not trying to boot over the network should just ignore the extra parameters.
The boot server/DHCP option #66 should specify the IP address of the system that contains the TFTP server, and the boot filename/option #67 should specify a valid TFTP pathname of the appropriate network boot program (NBP for short). For systems using legacy BIOS, PXELINUX is a common choice for a NBP.
For UEFI systems, you can probably use a grubx64.efi from your installation ISO image pretty much as-is (at least if you disable Secure Boot for the installation), but it seems to me that the ipxe.efi of the iPXE project might be more robust against UEFI netboot firmware bugs.
Newer UEFI systems may actually accept a HTTP URL in place of a boot file name; if they do, they can skip TFTP and proceed with using just HTTP for transferring all the boot files. This can speed up the netboot process by a significant amount.
Each of those Network Boot Programs will then want to first download a configuration file that will tell them how to proceed; typically it should be made available using either TFTP or HTTP, usually in the same directory the NBP boot file is, or in a specific sub-directory of it. See the documentation of your NBP of choice for details.
In the configuration file of the NBP, you can then specify the usual Linux boot essentials:

where to find a kernel file
where to find an initramfs file
which boot parameters to supply to the kernel

Again, your choice of NBP will determine the details here.
RedHat installation media will usually have a special kernel+initramfs file pair specifically for network installations; you'll find them in the images/pxeboot/ directory on the installation ISO.
For RedHat specifically, you'll need to supply a boot parameter to specify the URL where the main part of the installer (images/install.img on the installation ISO) can be found: for example, if it is available as http://server.example/rhel8/images/install.img, you would specify a boot parameter:
inst.stage2=http://server.example/rhel8

To skip some questions at the very beginning of the install process, you might also want to supply the boot parameters:
ip=dhcp inst.lang=en_US inst.keymap=us

(or whatever your preferred language and keyboard map choices are)
RedHat actually has a good document for the necessary setup.
Once you have the interactive network install of RHEL working, you will be in a good position to further automate the installation process by writing a Kickstart configuration file and adding a boot option to specify the URL where the installer can find it.
Described like this, setting up a network installation server may sound like a lot of work, but it really isn't.
